# Double Deck Solitaire for PC 1989-1992

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire, computers

Looking for the name and information on a solitaire game found in early releases of solitaire for the PC (circa 1989-1991).

It used two decks, eight foundation piles and a tableau with maybe 3 rows of 4 piles?

The object was to build up on the foundations (which began with queens perhaps).  One foundation went up by ones, one by twos, one by threes, and one by fours, I believe.

Was it called Queen Solitaire or King Solitaire, perhaps?

Comment: Might have better luck on Arqade: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a lot like [Picture Gallery Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Gallery_(solitaire)), a game that was put out for Palm.

I believe you can find an implementation on SourceForge.